# Chrome Extension date and time not updated when extension working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making extension. I get date and time with "getDateAndTime();" function.

```
function getDateAndTime() {
return (date.getDate()<10? "0" : "") + date.getDate() + " " + months_tr[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear() + " - " + (date.getHours()<10? "0" : "") + date.getHours() + "." + (date.getMinutes()<10? "0" : "") + date.getMinutes(); 
}
```

**The first time the extension runs, the date and time are updated, but then when the function is called again, the data is not updated.**

*How can I keep the date and time up to date?*

Comment: Where is `date` defined? How is it updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a date variable that declared out of the function.
It's declared once so it will remain the same.

I guess you want to add:

```
function getDateAndTime() {
    const date = new Date();
    ....
}
```

It means that the date is updated for everyone calls this function.